# Don't show array if its false

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code and its working:

```
 ...
   ],
    (
                        ($post['categories']['show'] ?
                            [
                                'name' => "categories",
                                'data' => ['categories' => self::getCategories($post)]
                            ] : ''
                ),
               [
               ...
```

However if its false its returning "" on the output but if its false it should not return nothing it should not show nothing. Do you know how to achieve that? With : null, it shows null, instead oof "",.

I also tried like this but don't works:

```
$result =         [
           
            'components' => [
                [
                  ...
                ],
               if($post['categories']['show'])
               {
                [
                    'name' => "categories",
                    'data' => ['categories' => self::getCategories($post)]
                ];
               }
                ....
               
        ];

        return $result;
    }
```

The whole code is really big. But it follows that structure array then ",".

Comment: There are better ways to conditionally add something to an array.

Comment: I agree with @nice_dev , you can add something to an array by array_push() or simple use `$result[] = $newElement;`.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that this 'categories' component should be on the position where it is. There are several components on the $results array and they need to have a specific order.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an empty string for the else conditional, use `null`, then use `array_filter`, it will clean all null values of the array for you:

```php
$result = [
 $condition ? 'bar' : null,
 'foobaz',
 ...
];

// return value will be: ["foobaz"]
return array_filter($result);
```